# How to transpose Columnar data into Row only 3 columns (Month )and Map the rest to them (NO GROUPING) using Azure DF/Synapse Pipeline/ SQL query

Tags: sql, azure, pivot, transpose, column-aggregation

Actual Header from CSV file

```
Supercategory   Segment Subsegment  Class   Total Property (Brand + License)    Corporate Manufacturer  Manufacturer    Brand   License Licensors   Model Number    Item Description    Jan 2022    Feb 2022    Jan 2022    Feb 2022    Jan 2022    Feb 2022    Jan 2022    Feb 2022    Jan 2022    Feb 2022    Jan 2022    Feb 2022
```

Output Expected:

```
COUNTRY LOCAL_CURRENCY  YEAR    MONTH   MONTH_YEAR  Supercategory   Segment Subsegment  Class   Total Property (Brand + License)    Corporate Manufacturer  Manufacturer    Brand   License Licensors   Model Number    Item Description    UNITS   AMOUNT_LC   AMOUNT_USD  % Distribution - Weighted   % of Stores Selling - Unweighted    $ Velocity - Weighted   Unit Velocity - Weighted    EXCHANGE_RATE
```

Below is the picture with Data in Actual file format and expected output (normalized)

[image: Sample shown image attached]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The expected output you want can be achieved with the help of dataflows in azure data factory (ADF studio -> Author -> Dataflow -> New dataflow). The following is the csv header of the sample data that I am using (similar to your csv) as the source.

```
Category    Segment    total_property(brand+license)    Jan 2022    Feb 2022    Jan 2022    Feb 2022    Jan 2022    Feb 2022
```

[image]

After configuring the source, create `unpivot` transformation to convert this column data of `Jan 2022` and `Feb 2022` to row data. Under this transformation, there are 3 important fields to be filled- Ungroup By, Unpivot Key and Unpivoted Columns. The following is how you fill these fields to achieve your requirement.

- Ungroup By: Select all the columns other than columns `Jan 2022` and `Feb 2022`

[image]

- Unpivot Key: Name this column as `Month_Year`, check `Enter values` and enter the values as following.

[image]

- Unpivoted Columns: Select Lateral column arrangement and add the columns that will be left after unpivot happens.

[image]

You can preview the data and the result would be like the following.

[image]

Since you want to add `Month` and `Year` column, create a `derived column` transformation. Add two columns naming `Month` with value as `month(toDate(month_year,'MMM yyyy'))` and `Year` with value as `year(toDate(month_year,'MMM yyyy'))`. The final data preview would be the expected output you want to get.

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** Since the csv has columns with same column names (`Jan 2022` and `Feb 2022`), dataflow is taking the values as `Jan 20223`, `Feb 20224` etc. But this does not affect the process.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation @saideep. But this file is reccuring by monthly basis with everymonth extending the columns from Jan, Feb, March,Arpil to DEC. is there a way we can do it dynamically in this mappping.